# How do I launch Dead By Daylight in exclusive Fullscreen mode?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

As in for whatever reason, my game decides that "Fullscreen" actually means "Borderless Windowed", which tanks the in-game performance considerably.

How do I launch Dead By Daylight in exclusive Fullscreen mode?  The PC Gaming wiki for optimizations doesn't list any sort of way to do so, but I see the term being used by others for optimization purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work - copied and edited slightly from [this Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/deadbydaylight/comments/7brj0z/how_to_play_in_exclusive_fullscreen_mode_fps_boost/):

> Go to *C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\DeadByDaylight\Saved\Config\WindowsNoEditor*
>   Open the file *GameUserSettings.ini* with Notepad.
>   Look for the following entries and change the value to `0`:
>
> `FullscreenMode=0`
>   `LastConfirmedFullscreenMode=0`
>   `PreferredFullscreenMode=0`
>
> To change the resolution, edit these settings as you wish:
>
> `ResolutionSizeX=1920`
>   `ResolutionSizeY=1080`
>   `LastUserConfirmedResolutionSizeX=1920`
>   `LastUserConfirmedResolutionSizeY=1080`
>
> Important, you need to add `-fullscreen` parameter to the launch options in Steam. (Right-click on the Dead by Daylight, and go to 'Properties', then 'Launch options').

Comment: You rock! This fixed this nonesence. I had misclicks since I had non 100% display scaling. I hated it so much.